# How to get Shipping/Billing Address ID of an order outside Magento core API?

Tags: php, magento

I want to get a shipping/billing address id from a just complete order out of Magento.

I have tried the following code but it's not worked:

> Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($array_data["order_id"])->getShippingAddressId()

Does someone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After uncountable debugging and googling, I got it solved:

For incremental order address id based on order,

```
$order_id=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$sales_order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
$billing_address_id=$sales_order->billing_address_id; 
$shipping_address_id=$sales_order->shipping_address_id;
```

For address entity id of the order based on customer,

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$billing_address_id=$quote->getBillingAddress()->customer_address_id;
$shipping_address_id=$quote->getShippingAddress()->customer_address_id;
```

Answer (score 15):

The following might help someone looking for a similar solution:

```
// Get the id of the last order for the current user(session)
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();        

// If an order actually exists
if ($orderId) {

    //Get the order details based on the order id ($orderId)
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

    // Get the id of the orders shipping address
    $shippingId = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();

    // Get shipping address data using the id
    $address = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($shippingId);

    // Display the shipping address data array on screen
    var_dump($address);

}
```

Note: Obviously this solution requires the user to have a current session

Good luck.

Comment: As also shown below, one can use `$address->getData()` and process via a `foreach($address->getData() as $key => $value)`. This answer was easiest solution for me.

Answer (score 7):

First, break apart your chained call to make make sure you're actually loading an order with

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($array_data["order_id"]);
var_dump($order->getData());
```

Assuming you've loaded the order, look at the values dumped above.  There's no `shipping_address_id`.  That, combined with there being no method  `getShippingAddressId` on a `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` is why your code isn't working.

Try

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($array_data["order_id"]);
$id    = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();
```

The `getShippingAddress` address method will return an address object, which you can inspect for its id.  If you look at the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` class definition, you can see the method definitions

```
//magento 1.4
public function getShippingAddress()
{
    foreach ($this->getAddressesCollection() as $address) {
        if ($address->getAddressType()=='shipping' && !$address->isDeleted()) {
            return $address;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function getAddressesCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_addresses)) {
        $this->_addresses = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_address_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setOrderFilter($this->getId());

        if ($this->getId()) {
            foreach ($this->_addresses as $address) {
                $address->setOrder($this);
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->_addresses;
}
```

The TL;DR for the code above is, address IDs aren't stored with the orders model.  The addresses for all orders are stored as a `sales/order_address` or `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address` object.

Comment: great walkthrough Alan.  A couple of minor typos in there "values *s*umped above" and "The *tl;dr* for the code above"

Cheers,
JD

Comment: I can't be expected to type correct english before noon. (thanks)

Comment: certainly not before caffeine :)  And BTW, I didn't realise that "tl;dr" was a deliberate abbreviation - thanks to urbandictionary for that one! :)

Comment: Thanks for your explaination on why it CAN'T work. Now I'd like to grant a solution of this problem. :-|

Comment: Heh, re-read the answer carefully carson.  I'm advising you use the order object to get a shipping object, and then get your address id from there.

Comment: Thanks. I can retrieve billing and shipping address id using getModel('sales/order'), but it seems to be an auto-incremental address id, instead of a customer address entity id, which I expect should be the same address id for different orders with same address. Could you give me some more advice on it?

Comment: Ah, got it.  I'm not sure if Magento stores that data once the order is placed (consider what would happen if a customer changed/deleted their entity id).  I'd poke around the methods on the sales/order_address model to see if anything is there. If not, I'd use the information in the sales/order_address object to try and match an existing customer address. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

//Get shipping address Id
$order->getShippingAddress()->getId();

//format output
echo $order->getShippingAddress()->format('html');

//Get shipping address data
print_r($order->getShippingAddress()->getData());
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This, you can get the shipping_address_id and billing_address_id

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('main_table.customer_id',$session->getId());
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($orderCollection as $order){
$shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($order->getShippingAddressId());
$billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($order->getBillingAddressId());
print_r($order->getData());
print_r($shippingAddress->getData());
print_r($billingAddress->getData());
}
```