# Magento. How to get address in quote

Tags: magento

I try to get address, which customer select in address step in checkout.

I use in /app/code/local/Mandarin/AddressTypeDiscount/Block/Onepage/Review.php this code:

```
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$bilAddress = $checkout->getBillingAddress();
$mylog = print_r($bilAddress, true);
Mage::log("addres:".$mylog, null, 'mygento.log');
```

but in my log file I get array of all customer`s addresses.

How I could get selected address in address step?
Thanks.

Comment: I use getData() for debuggin. getBillingAddress() retutns address, which set in customer as default, but I need address, which customer select in checkout steps

Comment: in quote data is default address attributes too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code seem to be correct see [Get billing information in order review section of one page checkout in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373183/get-billing-information-in-order-review-section-of-one-page-checkout-in-magento) .

`print_r($bilAddress, true)` will print the entire object, instead try `$bilAddress->getData()`

Try

```
 $checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
 $billAddress = $checkout->getBillingAddress();

 Mage::log($billAddress->getData());
```

Answer (score 2):

For incremental order address id based on order,

```
$order_id=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$sales_order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
$billing_address_id=$sales_order->billing_address_id; 
$shipping_address_id=$sales_order->shipping_address_id;
```

For address entity id of the order based on customer,

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$billing_address_id=$quote->getBillingAddress()->customer_address_id;
$shipping_address_id=$quote->getShippingAddress()->customer_address_id;
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600452/how-to-get-shipping-billing-address-id-of-an-order-outside-magento-core-api)